# Separate validation for day - month - year with Abide Foundation 4.3.2

Tags: regex, validation, zurb-foundation

thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

I am trying to validate the day / month / year as separate fields (a limitation of the system I can am building in) and am having trouble getting the validation on these to work.

I have tried adding custom patterns (throws console errors) and adding the regex to the fields (no errors, but always invalid even if the date is valid).

Any help would be great.

Code snippets:

I have tried adding custom patterns EG:

```
abide : {
patterns: {
  day_only: /0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]/,
  month_only: /0[1-9]|1[012]/,
  year_only: /.]\/(19|20)\d\d/,
}
```

}

And adding the regex to the fields directly (escaping the special characters) - no errors, but incorrect validation

```
<input type="tel" id="policyholder.dobdd" name="personalForm.dobdd" placeholder="DD" size="2" maxlength="2" required pattern="/(0/[1/-9/]/|/[12/]/\d/|3/[01/]/)" />
```

/

/